# Conversion of raster features to polylines: skeletonization?

Tags: raster, polygon, r, polyline-creation

I would like to identify linear features, such as roads and rivers, on raster maps and convert them to a linear vector features (i.e. polylines).  I typically use R as my primary GIS, and have posed this question as it pertains to R, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595117/identify-a-linear-feature-on-a-raster-map-and-return-a-linear-shape-object-using), at StackOverflow without resolution.  Apologies for cross-posting, however, here I am seeking any means to do this efficiently, (preferably, but not necessarily, in a manner that can be automated using code.)

Converting linear features of a certain class on a raster to polygons can be done using `rasterToPolygons()` in the R package `raster`, for example.  But how can I turn these polygons into polylines objects (i.e. skeletonize these polygons to a centre line) efficiently and reproducibly without resorting to to manual steps in vector graphics software, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mr. Huber described the steps to convert polygons to centerlines (Oct 17, 2002). I also found a centerline AML with the exact same steps. It looks pretty easy except you need to create Thiessen or Voronoi polygons as one of the steps.

SAGA/RSAGA creates Voronoi with a Nearest Neighbor module but only in a Grid format, so you might need to vectorize the grid if you go this route.

I recommend using Geoscript (geoscript.geom.geom.voronoi), it will create Voronoi as vectors.

You should be able to script the whole thing.
[centerline steps](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=3&f=38&t=76045)

Comment: Brilliant, nice find!  This just the elegant sort of algorithm I was looking for.  I believe there are multiple ways to do Voronoi tessellations in R.  This should be quite doable.

Comment: With your help @klewis I have now answered my own question on StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595117/identify-a-linear-feature-on-a-raster-map-and-return-a-linear-shape-object-using/9628816#9628816

Comment: It turns out that the `deldir` package does really efficient Voronoi tessellations, and it's a snap to find the centre-line thereafter.

Comment: Thanks to @Spacedman on StackOverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9643004/1165618) for developing an R-based solution to this problem.